# Special characters on table names Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

does anyone know how to include special characters like $ on a table name or if the table already exist with a $ on its name, how to ingest it on bigquery.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

BigQuery column names must contain only letters, numbers, and undescores.
They must start with either a letter or an underscore.

Link to relevant doc: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names

If a table contains special characters, you need to change its name before ingesting to BigQuery ($COLUMN_NAME -> DOLLAR_COLUMN_NAME, maybe?)

Comment: in this case the table comes from oracle named with dollar sign $ in it and I am migrating that db to bigquery.

Comment: How are you doing the export? It might be as simple as changing the column names in a like 'SELECT $col1 as ORA_COL1 from Table' (for example)